# Does View Binding support view binding for Adapter classes

Tags: android, android-layout, view, binding

I have just updated Android Studio to 3.6 and enabled View Binding in my project and I can use View Binding in my Fragments.

I have ListItemAdapter class which subclass from BaseExpandableListAdapter and I want to use View Binding for this class also. It seems it is not supported for Adapter Classes ?

As I mentioned above. I am using ExpandableListView. Below is code for inflating GroupView and ChildView inside expandableListView Adapter Class.

For now I am using KotlinX.android.synthetic

```
override fun getGroupView(
    groupPosition: Int,
    isExpanded: Boolean,
    convertView: View?,
    parent: ViewGroup?
): View {
    var convertView: View? = convertView
        ?: return context.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_parent_sidemenu, null)
    convertView!!.imgGroupIndicatorIcon.isSelected = isExpanded
    var headerTitle = getGroup(groupPosition) as String
    convertView!!.txtSideMenuParent.text = headerTitle
    return convertView!!
}


override fun getChildView(
    groupPosition: Int,
    childPosition: Int,
    isLastChild: Boolean,
    convertView: View?,
    parent: ViewGroup?
): View {
    var convertView: View? = convertView
        ?: return context.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_child_sidemenu, null)
    var childText = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition) as String
    convertView!!.txtSideMenuChild.text = childText
    return convertView!!
}
```

Comment: i think you can find your answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37656347/android-databinding-in-an-expandable-listview)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing what you tried and explaining in detail what you mean by "it is not supported for Adapter Classes". The `inflate()` methods on the generated view binding class should work anywhere that `inflate()` on a `LayoutInflater` does.

Comment: Off the cuff, you should be able to use view binding in both of those functions, to replace your existing `inflate()` calls.

Answer (score 1):

```
enter code here
```

val view  = BistItemParentSidemenuBinding
.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent, false).root

This above should work instead of

var convertView: View? = convertView
        ?: return context.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_child_sidemenu, null)